Wireshark not capturing http?
I'm using wireshark to capture packets on macOS on wifi en0 interface.
I read about http filter and wanted to try it sO I pressed capture button visited many websites and saw ton of traffic including Tcp but when I type http I see 0 results matching.
What am I doing wrong?
I made sure http is enabled in preferences and I'm using latest version of wireshark.
I wanted to capture the traffic from: http://www.example.com/index.html
If I write the following filter: tcp.port == 80 || udp.port == 80
I see packets with UDP or ICMP protocol.
Attaching my display and capture filters:



Everything is HTTPS (or QUIC) thesedays, not HTTP. You won't find much on Port 80 except maybe your router's settings page. Tapping-into HTTPS/QUIC means you need to MITM your own computer, as you're on macOS then I recommend Charles Proxy for that, not Wireshark: https://www.charlesproxy.com/

How do I view HTTP or HTTPS requests?.   Also check "Capture/Capture filters", make sure HTTP is not filtered.

@Luuk Hi, in filter tap I type http i'm using default setting, will add screenshots

@Dai the website I mentioned is http not https ):

@David example.com performs an automatic redirect from http: on port 80 to to https:  on port 443.

@Dai: no, curl -v http://www.example.com... has, in it's answer: "Connected to www.example.com (2606:2800:21f:cb07:6820:80da:af6b:8b2c) port 80"

@Luuk Yep - looks like it's my browser, Chrome, that's defaulting to HTTPS. My mistake. I assumed example.com was using HSTS or similar.

are you able to use http on your computers? why it's not working for me

When using the filter http i do see:
7829    12.870707   2606:2800:21f:cb07:6820:80da:af6b:8b2c  2a02:a466:93a7:1:4023:78c9:d668:2f53    HTTP    447 HTTP/1.1 200 OK  (text/html)



I tried http and I don't see anything on macOS, I gave wireShark full disk access as well.

Also make sure that under Capture/Options/Input the correct interface is checked.

I am, can i share my pcap file so you may take a look? i turned off macOS firewall as well.

sorry, I happened to have an install of Wireshark, but need to do some learning, fiddling to get to know it better.....
